# Как сделать полоску(нижнию) как на TechCrunch.com?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать полоску(нижнию) как на TechCrunch.com?

Comment: А как там?

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/
Черная полоска снизу, где написано 

AolTech
Privacy Policy © 2012 AOL Inc. All rights reserved. Powered by WordPress.com VIP



------------------
Пытался так сделать, но походу так наследуется значение родителя.
#bottomLine 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000;
    position: static;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9999; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background: #191919;
color: #343434;
display: block;
font: normal normal 400 10px/normal Arial;
height: 13px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
width: 935px;
```

Можете не благодарить.

Comment: нет, получается такое:
http://SSMaker.Ru/4ce61fd3/
код
#bottomLine 
{
background: #191919;
color: #343434;
display: block;
font: normal normal 400 10px/normal Arial;
height: 13px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

Comment: А нет, все ок.
Спасибо.